# ORA-00923 error: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle10g

When calculating retention on Oracle DB, I wrote this code:

```
select 
sessions.sessionDate , 
count(distinct sessions.visitorIdd) as active_users, 
count(distinct futureactivity.visitorIdd) as retained_users,
count(distinct futureactivity.visitorIdd) / count(distinct sessions.visitorIdd)::float as retention
FROM sessions
left join sessions futureactivity on
sessions.visitorIdd=futureactivity.visitorIdd
and sessions.sessionDate = futureactivity.sessionDate - interval '3' day
group by 3;
```

but I always get the error: "ORA-00923: mot-clé FROM absent à l'emplacement prévu" (ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected)
Can you help me guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more "Oracle" way of writing the query:

```
select s.sessionDate , 
       count(distinct s.visitorIdd) as active_users, 
       count(distinct fs.visitorIdd) as retained_users,
       count(distinct fs.visitorIdd) / count(distinct s.visitorIdd) as retention
from sessions s left join
     sessions fs
     on s.visitorIdd = fs.visitorIdd and
        s.sessionDate = fs.sessionDate - interval '3' day
group by s.sessionDate
order by s.sessionDate;
```

Notes:

- Oracle does not require conversion with dividing integers.
- The `group by` should contain the column name, and it is actually "1", not "3".
- Shorter table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You'll probably want an `order by`, because the results will be an in indeterminate order.
- There is probably a better way to write this query using window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not recognize `::` syntax of Postgres, so it complains of the missing `FROM` keyword not being found where expected.

Use a cast instead:

```
count(distinct futureactivity.visitorIdd) / cast(count(distinct sessions.visitorIdd) as float) as retention
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked but another error came up :/

Comment: I am following the code from this link: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-calculate-cohort-retention-in-sql.html

Comment: the new error is: "ORA-00979: N'est pas une expression GROUP BY"

Comment: This query is too much Postgres, it wouldn't work in Oracle. It's much better to understand how it works, and then write it yourself from scratch, than figuring out the translation.

Comment: Will do. Thanks a lot. I appreciate the advice.